# How can I replace %userprofile% with current user?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, path, environment-variables

I am not very skilled in VB. I would like to keep this simple code. I want to use this code for another computer or user. How can I replace my usermane "John" in the code?

I tried replace it with `%userprofile%` and similar words but it´s not working.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(
        "C:\Users\John\Desktop\WindowsApp.exe",
        "C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\WindowsApp.exe")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables) method:

```
Dim userProfileBaseDir As String = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%userprofile%")
```

This returns:

```
C:\Users\[CurrentUser]
```

Your code could be:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(
    $"{userProfileBaseDir}\Desktop\WindowsApp.exe",
    $"{userProfileBaseDir}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs\Startup\WindowsApp.exe")
```

But, since both **`Desktop`** and **`StartMenu`** are included in the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enumerator, see: [Environment.SpecialFolder enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Environment.SpecialFolder);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.8)

The [Environment.GetFolderPath()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath) method converts the enumeration to a Path.
Using interpolated strings:

```
Dim desktopPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
Dim menuStart As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup)

My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile($"{desktopPath}\WindowsApp.exe", $"{menuStart}\WindowsApp.exe")
```

Or using [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) to build a path:

```
Dim sourcePath = Path.Combine(desktopPath, "WindowsApp.exe")
Dim destPath = Path.Combine(menuStart, "WindowsApp.exe")

FileSystem.CopyFile(sourcePath, destPath)
```

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Environment.SpecialFolder` Enum for both paths. And use `Path.Combine` to build paths.

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(
    System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "WindowsApp.exe"),
    System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup), "WindowsApp.exe"))
```

Perhaps `WindowsApp.exe` is the name of your executing application. Now you have no hard-coding

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(
    System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName),
    System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup), System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName))
```

Or you want to copy the currently running application to startup

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(
    Application.ExecutablePath,
    System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup), System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile( "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\Desktop\WindowsApp.exe", "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\WindowsApp.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a **quick** and **ready-to-use** code, you can try this:

```
Dim userProfileDir As String
userProfileDir = Environ("USERPROFILE")
```

If your user is called `IT`, `MsgBox userProfileDir` would show this:

[image]

---

In your code it would be somenthing like this:

```
Dim sourcePath As String  'C:\User\MyUser
Dim destinationPath As String  'C:\User\MyUser\AppData\Roaming

sourcePath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\WindowsApp.exe"
destinationPath = Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\WindowsApp.exe"

FileSystem.CopyFile(sourcePath, destinationPath)
```

Hope this helps.